# Can I end a sentence with "not on a par"?

Tags: grammaticality

Can I end the below sentence with "on a par"?

> Researchers have the ability to get all the data, however, the ability to make conclusions using that data is not on a par.

I intended to say that researchers have powerful equipment for data mining, but they do not have the necessary skills to use that data in research.

Can I end it as shown above or should I change it to "not on a par with..."? Please help.

Comment: What is the intended meaning?  It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal construction is [*X is on (a) par with Y*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20a%20par).

Strictly speaking, you *could* write your sentence like this (I've made one correction):

> Researchers have the ability to get all the data; however, **their** ability to make conclusions using that data is not on a par **with it**.

But that's somewhat awkward, not least of all because the referent of the pronoun at the end takes a bit of parsing to figure out. (And replacing it with a repetitious *their ability to get all the data* would be even more unwieldy.)

---

If you're going to use *on a par with*, I would restructure the sentence altogether:

> The ability of researchers to get all the data is not on a par with their ability to make conclusions using that data.

---

Note that if I interpret the meaning of this sentence correctly (I was only commenting on the syntax), it would be simpler to say:

> Researchers are better at gathering data than drawing conclusions.